# Limit of a sequence multiply by a constant

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-verification

If the sequence $s_n$ converges to $s$, then for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$ the sequence $ks_n$ converges to $ks$.

Proof: We assume that $k \neq 0$ since the result is trivial for $k = 0$ .

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and note that we have to proof $|ks_n - ks| < \epsilon$ for large n. Since $\lim s_n = s$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$n > N$ implies: $$|s_n - s| < \frac{\epsilon}{|k|}$$

which also implies: $$|ks_n - ks| < \epsilon$$

My question might sound dumb because the logic is pretty obvious because $\lim (ks_n) = k \cdot \lim s_n$. But I don't quite understand why does the proof starts with $|s_n - s| < \frac{\epsilon}{|k|}$? In another words, why do we have $\frac{\epsilon}{|k|}$?

Appreciate for the one who helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They did that because they want to end up with $|ks_n-ks|< \epsilon$, so they can show that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}ks_n = ks$.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that was the result that we want to prove?

Comment: It is proved, because we *know* that there is an $N$ such that $|s_n - s| < \frac{\epsilon}{|k|}$ for all $n > N$. (This is thanks to the definition of limits and the fact that we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n=s$.) If that inequality holds, then so does the inequality $|ks_n - ks|< \epsilon$.

Comment: Let say we want to prove $\lim(s_n + t_n) = \lim s_n + \lim t_n$ = s + t. Then we can have the equation as $|s_n - s| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and  $|t_n - t| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. And then we add them together. This concept implies as long as the definition of limit was satisfied? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you would use $\epsilon/2$ there and add! But you have to make sure to justify why those two inequalities imply that $|(s_n+t_n)-(s+t)|<\epsilon$, and to do this, you would use the *triangle inequality*. That is, note that $|(s_n+t_n)-(s+t)| = |(s_n-s)+(t_n-t)|\le |s_n-s | + |t_n-t|$, by the triangle inequality. Also, you would need to make sure to take your $N$ for this inequality to be something $\ge$ both $N_1$ and $N_2$, where $N_1$ is such that $|s_n-s| \le \epsilon/2$ whenever $n\ge N_1$ and $N_2$ similarly for the $t$ sequence. You can probably find a proof written up online.

Comment: Oh yes! I got you! Thanks!